# How To Wrap A Div When Parent Container Shrinks Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS issue I can't figure out. Here is the markup.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .container { position: relative; background-color: purple; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            .first { float: left; width: 10%; min-width: 100px; background-color: yellow; }
            .second { float: left; width: 10%; min-width: 100px; background-color: orange; }
            .third { float: left; width: 80%; background-color: lime; }
            .clear { clear: both; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="first">first</div>
            <div class="second">second</div>
            <div class="third">third</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</hmtl>
```

The issue I'm having is that I want to wrap the third div when I shrink the browser window, but have it fully expanded (100%) once it wraps to a new line. I'm close, but when the third div wraps, the 80% with property kicks in and doesn't allow it to fully expand. [I have a fiddle ready for tweaking here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Halcyon/HU7r9/1/) Below are images which visualize the problem. You can see in the second image that the third div isn't 100% expanded when the wrapping takes place.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, no pure CSS solution. Use jQuery...

You want to attach an event to the window.resize. Caution is that the window.resize refreshes constanstanly, so a little extra function is needed to wait for the resize to stay constant for half a second before you fire your method.

Markup

```
<div>
    <div id="firstcont" style="float:left; display:inline-block;">
        <select></select>
        <select></select>
    </div>
    <div id="secondcont" style="margin-left:80px;">
        <input id="note" style="width: 99%;" /><br />
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    //wait a half second for a consant resize reading before executing
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){

        var $textbox = $("#note");
        var textboxwidth = $textbox.width();

        //alert(textboxwidth);

        if(textboxwidth < 400)
        {
            //alert("resizing");
            $('#firstcont').css('float', 'none');
            $('#secondcont').css("margin-left", "0px");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#firstcont').css('float', 'left');
            $('#secondcont').css("margin-left", "80px");
        }
    }, 500, "some unique string");
});

var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
  var timers = {};
  return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
    if (!uniqueId) {
      uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
    }
    if (timers[uniqueId]) {
      clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
    }
    timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eastonharvey/Nsgf8/2/

Answer (score 0):

the atribute min-width in the classes .first & .second are the problem

if you remove it, have another behavior

Answer (score -1):

try this,
 here's the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2ETAS/)

```
    .container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 400px;
}
.first {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;

    background-color: yellow;
}
.second {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;

    background-color: orange;
}
.third {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: lime;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't wrap when I shrink the iframe in jsfiddle.

Comment: That's doesn't do what OP is trying to accomplish